# Is it possible to implement a Firebug-like "inspect element" DOM element highlighter with client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to show an arbitrary web page (call it the target web page) in an `iframe` element of a host webpage, and let the use select and highlight a `div` box in the target web page (in the iframe) and return information about that selection (e.g. the xpath to that node) to the host web page?

This is essentially Firebug's inspect-element feature, but implemented with javascript and using an iframe to hold the webpage that is being inspected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), as this may be exactly what you're looking for

**Edit**:  just to clarify, I'm not talking about using Firebug Lite as an extension, but as in included js, as is mentioned near the bottom of the page I referenced.  Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK thanks. but can you make this work not on the page that is loaded, but on a page loaded from a different domain in an iframe?

Comment: @dan I think I see what you're getting at, and it's a good question, the only thing I can think to do is somehow use jQuery to inject the firebug-lite script tag into the page loaded in the iframe.